# jQuery Tools Validator and not applicable select option

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-tools

I am using jquery tools validator plugin to validate form input. I have a select box in the for m that needs to be validated against, but I need to ignore the validation if the "not applicable" option is choosen.

```
<select id="state" required="required">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="">*Not applicable</option>
```

It'll validate fine if the value is empty, but how would I go about setting a rule to exclude the Not Applibale option from the validation?

Answer (score 0):

You should do validationg work programmatically:

```
if(jQuery("#state option:selected").text() !== "*Not applicable") {
    // validate
}
```

Comment: seems that this still doesnt meet the requirement. I am still having issues.